# Nodejs express performance

Tags: node.js, performance, express, amazon-kinesis, throughput

I am running a nodejs/express app which pushes click stream events to kinesis streams. On a compute optimized ec2 node instance, with 8 cores, i am able to process only 5k requests / second. Kinesis isn't the bottleneck, it has enough shards and no provisioned throughput exception etc. Nodejs/express isn't able to process beyond 5k requests / second on a compute optimized ec2 instance.

Even a simple 200 status return route has only 6k req/second throughput. setup that i have is 6 docker containers running with host networking and i have nginx on the same host configured with these 6 containers as upstream.

Any pointers on where to look for? Throughput seems to be very low considering the fact it's a compute optimized instance (c5.2xlarge).

Answer (score 0):

check nginx error logs if you are getting any errors there, or if cpu is consumed too much when you reach 6k throughput, check what is getting bottlenecked, containers, or the load balancer. if the cpu is consumed too much please re-check your code.